# Good C# bidirectional socket client implementation?

Tags: c#, sockets, client

I cant find any good implementations in c# of a bidirectional socket client. An ideal implementation will try to connect the socket until it succeed. Then it will start receiveing messages and at the same time shall I be abel to send messages to the socket server.

Does any bode have a good example of this?

Thanks!

Comment: ANY socket is bidirectional. TCP is so per definition. IT was designed to be bidirectional.

Answer (score 2):

`System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient` is bi-directional.